# Proving equivalence relations involving determinants of two vectors

Tags: equivalence-relations

I was told to prove that the following is an equivalence relation:

The relation R on the set $U = \{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x_2 \ne 0\}$ is given by 
$$\forall\,(x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2) \in U, \quad (x_1,x_2)\,R\,(y_1,y_2) \;\Longleftrightarrow\; \det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

I was able to show that $R$ is reflexive and symmetric. However, I am having trouble showing that it is transitive. I triesd starting off by showing that $\det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$ and $\det \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ z_1 & z_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$ but i don't know where to go after that. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I don't understand what the definition of U means.

Comment: Is $\det[(x_1 y_2) - (x_2 y_1)]$ supposed to be $\det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2\end{bmatrix} = x_1y_2 - x_2y_1$?

Comment: @Misha yes that is how it was written but I did not know how to write in that format in the text box.

Comment: I've edited the post for you; hopefully I haven't introduced any errors in the process.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that $$\det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2\end{bmatrix} = 0$$ is equivalent to saying that the vectors $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ are collinear. You can get this from some linear algebra: if the determinant is $0$, the matrix is not full rank, so its second row is a multiple of the first. But it's probably simpler to just rewrite the condition $x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 = 0$ as $\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{y_1}{y_2}$, given that we're told $x_2 \ne 0$ whenever $(x_1,x_2) \in U$.

In that case, it's straightforward to prove transitivity: if $(x_1,x_2)\,R\,(y_1,y_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)\,R\,(z_1,z_2)$, then $\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{y_1}{y_2}$ and $\frac{y_1}{y_2} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$, so by transitivity of *equality* we have $\frac{x_1}{x_2} = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$ which can be rewritten as $(x_1,x_2)\,R\,(z_1,z_2)$.

(Note that we did need $x_2 \ne 0$ in the definition of $U$. If we allow the element $(0,0)$ to be in $U$, then $(x_1,x_2)\,R\,(0,0)\,R\,(y_1,y_2)$ for any $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$, which breaks transitivity.)

It's generally a good idea, when dealing with equivalence relations, to look for a function "characterizing" them: some function $f$ such that $a\,R\,b$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$. This makes proving that relation is an equvalence relation a lot easier, and generally gives you helpful insight into how $R$ works.